Почему в шапке сайта начал скрываться телефон компании?
Есть сайт:
https://evroflag24.ru/
После нахождение на нём секунд 10, телефон компании скрывается каким-то бело-прозрачным градиентом. Почему? Как исправить?


Наверное потому что кто-то так сделал. Если посмотрите в инспекторе кода, то номер телефона там разбит посимвольно и каждый из символов обернута в тег small с инлайновыми стилями и разной opacity.

Копайте в сторону подключённого скрипта https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag_phone.js?ver=1513&b=pnf

Кто-то кому-то не заплатил))

Причём скрипт отрабатывает только в одну сторону)
